# writing twice using filewriter api in html5 leads to error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to use BlobBuilder and FileWriter API in HTML to write data to the file.
My problem is that if I use write function twice, I get an error. The following
code executes OK:

```
  var bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder();
  bb.append('LOREL');
  outWriter.write(bb.getBlob('text/plain'));
```

But if I change it as follows (try to write twice)

```
  var bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder();
  bb.append('LOREL');
  outWriter.write(bb.getBlob('text/plain'));
  bb.append('LOREL');
  outWriter.write(bb.getBlob('text/plain'));
```

I get an error. The error code is: `INVALID_STATE_ERR`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `FileWriter.write()` is asynchronous and you're trying to write more data to the file before the first write has complete. According to [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html#widl-FileWriter-write-void-Blob-data), a `FileException` should be thrown if `readyState==WRITING`. Likely what's happening in your case. You need something like:

```
var bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder();
bb.append('LOREL');

outWriter.onwrite = function(e) {
  bb.append('LOREL');
  outWriter.write(bb.getBlob('text/plain'));
};

outWriter.write(bb.getBlob('text/plain'));
```

Also, I hope your code snippet is just an example and you're not actually appending, writing, appending, writing. Otherwise, use one `write()`:

```
var bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder();
bb.append('LOREL');
bb.append('LOREL');
outWriter.write(bb.getBlob('text/plain'));
```